# What exactly does resolveConflictingSavedGames in GameKit do?

Tags: ios, gamekit

According to the documentation, The *GameKit* function `resolveConflictingSavedGames` resolves conflicting saved games. However, I don't really understand what it does exactly, and how to use it.

- Does it replace the data in all saved games in the provided
  conflictingSavedGames array with the data provided in Data?
- Do I have
  to handle the `GKSavedGame` passed to the completion handle in some
  way? I.e manually erase the old ones and save the new savedgame?
- Am I supposed to call it when loading or saving?
- Should I always call it when there are multiple savedgames tied to one filename?

The function:

```
 func resolveConflictingSavedGames(
      _ conflictingSavedGames: [GKSavedGame],   
      with data: Data, 
      completionHandler handler: (([GKSavedGame]?, Error?) -> Void)? = nil)
```

[Documentation for resolveConflictingSavedGames](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/gamekit/gklocalplayer/1521116-resolveconflictingsavedgames)

Comment: Hello. I know this is a very old post, but I can't find much information about this. Did you happen to learn any more? I am totally stuck trying to get resolveConflictingSavedGames working for my project. Thank you in advance